# PowerApps screen caching

Tags: powerapps-forms, cache

I have an app with a gallery view screen to show a list of items in a SharePoint list. If you select an item in that gallery and click on a view item icon, it opens a Display form for that item. If I want to edit that item, I click the Edit button on the Display screen. That opens an Edit form. The first time I edit the item, my current version of the Edit form displays. However, if I return to the item after making an update and submitting the form via a button, the edit screen that launches is an old version of my edit screen. I am clicking the same Edit button from the same Display screen in both instances. Has anyone encountered this behavior before, and if so, do you have any fixes for it aside from build a new Edit form from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, one reason could be that your gallery is using a collection as your data source and your submit button is saving directly to your SharePoint list. If that is the case, you would need to update your collection after saving the data to the SharePoint list.

If you could provide some more detail and screenshots of your app, I think we'd be able to give you a more definitive answer.

Comment: The gallery is not using a collection. It is pulling directly from the back-end SharePoint list.